# How to check whether a number is hex or decimal in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, decimal, basic

I have a VB.NET application which get a number to a string variable through Serial Port and I need to check if the number  in is a hexadecimal or decimal.
one number is obtained from a RFID reader.

It consists of at least one letter from A to F like 7AA29B1A and other one only consists of numbers. For example, 145744. It is obtained from a barcode reader. If it is a hex number I want to put it in to a variable like in the code and if it is a decimal number assign it to a different variable.

```
Private Sub TimerSerialIn_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerSerialIn.Tick
    Try
        StrSerialIn = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        LabelConnectionStatus.Text = "Connection Status : Connected"
        If StrSerialIn <> "" Then
            If GetID = True Then
                LabelGetID.Text = StrSerialIn
                GetID = False
                If LabelGetID.Text <> "________" Then
                    PanelReadingTagProcess.Visible = False
                    IDCheck()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If the string only contains the digits from 0 to 9, how could you possibly tell whether it's decimal or hexadecimal. Does the text "10" represent then number ten in decimal or sixteen in hexadecimal? Why would you be getting a number as text without knowing the format beforehand in the first place?

Comment: The proper way to identify a hexadecimal number to avoid the confusion I mentioned above is prefix it with "0x". If you really are passing decimal and hexadecimal numbers as text and you need to distinguish between them then you should just be able to look for that prefix, but I don't really understand why you'd be asking this question if the data really was in that format.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I have corrected it now.

Comment: The question is still incomplete. You have provided one example each of a hexadecimal number and a decimal number but you haven't told us what the rules are. You cannot be vague when writing code because computers won't just work out what you mean from context. If you can't explain exactly what every rule is that the code has to implement then you haven't thought about the problem enough. For instance, in your examples, the hex number is 8 digits and the decimal number is six digits. Is that a rule? If so then say so. If not then what are the rules? You do realise that 145744 is valid hex?

Comment: Hey, sorry for that. The decimal number always consist of 6 digits it is going to be read by a barcode reader and the hex number always consist at least one letter. It is a number read from a rfid tag. I want to identify these two numbers in the program and take two different actions for two number formats.

Comment: So then your question is actually how to determine whether a `String` contains at least one letter. `If myString.Any(Function(ch) Char.IsLetter(ch)) Then`. If there might be values that aren't valid in either case then you can be more specific in your testing, e.g. test whether the `Length` is 6, all characters are digits, or all characters are either digits or contained in a list of specific characters. `If myString.Length = 6 AndAlso myString.All(Function(ch) Char.IsDigit(ch)) Then`, `ElseIf myString.All(Function(ch) Char.IsDigit(ch) OrElse {"A"c, "B"c, ...}.Contains(ch)) Then`.

Comment: Thank you  jmcilhinney. I will try that.